# IOS Widgets, Identify multiple Widget with same kind

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I need to create an illimited number of widgets, with the same layout, but with different behavior and content.

When the user adds many widgets of the same type, the `kind` will be the same. I need something else to identify the widgets in order to set a different behavior from each other. Do they have an Id?

Comment: `- kind: A unique string that you choose.` I think, by some means, it is the 'Id'.

Comment: the same widget added twice will have the same kind, then I need something different that identifies the single widget even if duplicated in the home screen.

Comment: Curious why do you need to differentiate them? If you want a unique id, just use `UUID()`

Comment: Explained in the question.
You can't give an uid to the widget

Comment: No, but I didn't try again since the last comments

Answer (score 0):

You could add a configuration parameter with dynamic options. Create a custom intent for the configuration, and set it for your widget [as described in the documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/staticconfiguration) You can provide parameters to setup your widget, and they can be complex types if needed.

Let's say that in the app you "create" a new widget, you can save it somewhere with a specific name, or ID, with its defined behaviour.
Then in the widget configuration screen, you can display the list of the different widgets, and select the one you want.

You can then get the configuration when you build your widget, and change the behaviour as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the answer from @hellimac

1. Make this widget configurable by creating an `Siri Intent Definition File` in the new file window.
2. Then you can get your intent class in your `IntentTimelineProvider` in the `getTimeline` function
3. Every widget from the same kind share the same DataProvider instance,but they have different Intent.
4. You can get the intent identifier by calling `configuration.identifier` which can differentiate the same kind widget, and you can provide different data based on the identifier.

```
 func getTimeline(for configuration: ViewImageIntent,in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<DataEntry>) -> Void) {
     print(configuration.identifier)
     // your code here
}
```

Comment: I'm using WidgetConfigurationIntent (which inherits from AppIntent), but there is no property `identifier` there. Could you tell more about this?

Comment: @nightwill Sorry for the misleading,  this intent is not created by code and does not inherit App Intent,  but by creating a new type of Siri Ientent Definition file. Then Xcode will automatically generate the class of code for you,  which is the `ViewImageIntent` above.

Comment: I just tried creating an Intent file and then checked the  `identifier`. For all added widgets it is the same (I display it on the screen). After I change the parameters in “Edit widget...”, some of the widgets (`Intent`) change the `identifier`, but in most cases they are still the same

Comment: I tested it again, and yes you are right, it seems like if you use a different sale of the widget, the identifier has a chance to be different, but for the widget with the same size, they are always the same.

Comment: @nightwill But if you set the intent parameter to a different value, the identifier will be different.